# Where is the pseudo-distributed template for HBase?

Tags: configuration, hbase

The [HBase documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/pseudo-distributed.html) asks me to Copy the pseudo-distributed suggested configuration file

```
cp conf/hbase-site.xml{.pseudo-distributed.template,}
```

But there is no such file!

```
cp: cannot stat `conf/hbase-site.xml.pseudo-distributed.template': No such file or directory
```

Where can I find that template?

Comment: Sure doesn't appear to be there. Maybe ask on the HBase user list? http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing. You can find it in packages that came before to 0.9. See the [bug tracker entry](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5822)